# Java Generics with Reflection for Visitor Pattern

Tags: java, generics, reflection, visitor-pattern

I want to make sure this will work before my code gets too big/complicated to post. I do not have enough to test if this works the way I expect

I'm working on something in which I'd like to use the Visitor pattern on an AST. My goal is to make the fact that the visitor is there almost transparent when implementing a new type of TreeNode, by eliminating the need to override `accept(Visitor)` in every subclass by using reflection in the superclass.

By allowing a `visit(TreeNode)` it allows a default method for unknown Node types, that way old visitors don't need to be altered when a new node type is added.

The class Parameters R and P are a return value and parameter for the visiting, a trick I picked up at this [programming stack exchange question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189476/implementing-the-visitor-pattern-for-an-abstract-syntax-tree).

To do this I have the following:

```
public abstract class TreeNode {
    public final < R, P > R accept(TreeVisitor<R,P> v, P p){
        try{
            Method m = v.getClass().getMethod("visit", getClass(),Object.class);
            return (R)m.invoke(v, this,p);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme){
        }
        return (R)v.visit(this,p);
    }
    public abstract void contains(TreeNode n);//and other methods
}
//in another file
interface TreeVisitor<R,P> {
    public R visit(TreeNode n,P p);//default
    public R visit(TreeNodeSubclass tns,P p);
    //all other subclasses as well
}
//from here lower is un-tested, written just now, just for this post, code
//somewhere else we have an algorithm to visit nodes
class DoStuff implements TreeVisitor<String,Void>{
     public String visit(TreeNode n, Void v){
          return n.toString();
     }
     public String visit(TreeNodeSubclass n, Void v){
         return "SUB:" + n.toString();
     }
}

//algorithm in a method somewhere
DoStuff ds = new DoStuff();
for(TreeNode node : inOrderTraverse(ROOT_NODE)){
     node.accept(ds);
}
```

Will this work as I expect (assuming `inOrderTraverse(ROOT_NODE)` produces a list of all nodes properly)?

My main question is actually the part with the `getMethod` call, because of type erasure `Object.class` should be the correct parameter even though one would prefer to use `p.getClass()` because of the generic parameter `P`. That however wouldn't work because type erasure causes the actual method signature in the Visitor to be `Object visit(this.getClass(), Object)`, the `this.getClass()` referring to the fact that I'm using the actual class of the subclass of the Node to get the proper overloaded method in the Visitor.

Is my understanding of this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's going to work if you pass in Object.class as a parameter type, but I do see another potential issue:
If your new Nodes have a private instead of a public "visit" method, then you should account for it in the exception, e.g:

```
try{
            Method m = v.getClass().getMethod("visit", getClass(),Object.class);
            return (R)m.invoke(v, this,p);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        try {
            Method m = v.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("visit", getClass(),Object.class);
            return (R)m.invoke(v, this,p);  
            } catch (Exception e){
            return (R)v.visit(this,p);//default
            }   
        } catch (Exception e){
            return (R)v.visit(this,p);//default
        }
```

Comment: They should have a public method, because they will implement the Visitor interface. Also `Exception e` is probably not the best thing for me to catch for the default. (editing OP to reflect this)